# Netezza migration to Azure Synapse - Stored Procedures?

Tags: stored-procedures, migration, azure-sql-database, netezza

I have looked everywhere for useful documentation that comprehensively gives me the differences between Netezza stored procedures and functions so I can find Azure Synapse equivalents.

Is there any site or link that documents this sort of thing without having to look up each individual incompatibility by running the procs in Azure and having them fail?

I guess I would like to proactively fix these rather than reactively fixing them to save time

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Synapse Pathway is a new tool currently in preview which can look at existing Netezza code for you, attempt to convert it and flag up errors.

Download the tool and run it against your Netezza installation.  Start here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/synapse-pathway/azure-synapse-pathway-overview?view=azure-sqldw-latest

As a wizard, it's probably at best going to give you 80/20, but will at least offer a start.

Comment: I'm interested in any feedback you have on Pathway as it's in preview and I'm sure MS will be too.